# How to add model variable to another model in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

My problem is this I have `$collaborator` (model) variable in my view. In the view there is form related with `$permission` model. Now I need add `$permission` to My view file. How can I do it my blade view is this
 I need print status value of the permission table on this blade file. That I need get `$permission` here.

My blade file is

```
 @if($collaborators) // I need add $permission here
           @foreach( $collaborators as $collaborator)
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <span>
                            <img src="{{ $collaborator->user()->first()->getAvatarUrl() }}" />
                             {{ $collaborator->user()->first()->username}}
                             {{ $collaborator->user()->first()->id}}

                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger delete" style="margin-top:5px;padding:4px;width:35px;"
                      data-action="/projects/{{ $project->id }}/collaborators/{{ $collaborator->collaborator_id }}"
                      data-token="{{csrf_token()}}">
                    <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                    </button>

                    <!-- permission start -->

                    <form class="form-vertical" role="form" method="post" action="{{ route('projects.collaborators.permission', $project->id,$collaborator->id) }}">
                        <!--<div id="cid" name="cid">{{ $collaborator->user()->first()->id}}</div>-->
                    <input type="hidden" id="cid" name="cid" value="{{ $collaborator->user()->first()->id }}" />
                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('status') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                    <label for="status" class="control-label">Choose Permission</label>
                    <select name="status" id="status">
                    <option value="">Choose a status</option>
                    <option value="3">View Only</option>
                    <option value="2">Edit Tasks</option>
                    <option value="1">Admin</option>
                    </select>
                    @if ($errors->has('status'))
                    <span class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('status') }}</span>
                    @endif
                    </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Create</button>
                      </div>
                      <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token()
```

Comment: Are your models related (*BelongsTo*, *HasMany*)? Did you try `$collaborator->permission` from your view ?

Comment: If your models are related you can access `$permission` as related property as mentioned by @alariva. However, in case your models are not related you can calculate the value of `$permission` within your controller method and pass it as a variable to the blade view along with `$collaborator` - probably something like `return view('blade-view', compact('collaborator', 'permission)); or return view('blade-view')->with('collaborator', 'permission');`